# Wanted: WCF Custom Binding with binaryMessageEncoding & transport security

Tags: wcf

I'm a newb to WCF bindings and would appreciate any help making a custom binding that:

- Supports Binary Message encoding.
- Uses Transport Security (clientCredentialType="None").

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to create a custom binding in your `<system.serviceModel>` section of the config - something like this:

```
<bindings>
  <customBinding>
    <binding name="HttpBinaryBinding">
      <binaryMessageEncoding />
      <httpTransport />
    </binding>
  </customBinding>
</bindings>
```

There's a ton of features and options you can define here - the sequence of the elements is important - message encoding before transport, and transport is the last of the options in the stack. See the [MSDN Docs on Custom Bindings](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wcf/extending/custom-bindings) or Kirk Evans' [blog post](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/kaevans/wcf-and-custom-bindings) for more details on all available options and rules how to combine them.

Once you've defined your custom binding, you can use it by specifying `binding="customBinding"` and then `bindingConfiguration="HttpBinaryBinding"` on your endpoints - both on the server side as well as on the client side.

```
    <endpoint
      address="http://localhost:8001/myService/"
      binding="customBinding"
      bindingConfiguration="HttpBinaryBinding"
      contract="IMyService"
      name="customHttpBindingEndpoint" />
```

That's really all there is!

Comment: Thanks for the reply. 
I looked at the links provided but I can't find any example to add Transport security to the binding.

Comment: @Bram: use the <httpsTransport /> instead of <httpTransport />

Comment: Thanks Marc_s. How more question, if I use httpsTransport, the contents of the data being sent to the WCF service is encrypted right?

Comment: @Bram: using httpsTransport encrypts everything on the communications link. However: transport security typically only works in company environments behind corporate firewalls - over the internet, you cannot guarantee transport security all the way from the client to your server.